# FrozenTime object mistery

Tags: php, mysql, object, cakephp, time

I found a strange case in a FrozenTime object.

I get data from a find() and I send it to the view as usual. One particular field comes from a MySQL time column.

The table name is `sessions` and the field is called `time`.

When iterating the resulset, this column becomes:

```
object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

    'time' => '2017-07-14T01:00:50+00:00',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'fixedNowTime' => false

}
```

The mistery starts when calling  `debug($session->time->format('G:i:s'));` With this, I get a **Call to a member function format() on null** error.

While trying to solve the issue, I did:

```
$moment = $session->time;
debug($moment instanceof \Cake\I18n\FrozenTime);
```

and I got a `true` as an answer. Strange to be null (as the error says) if it is actually an object with content. And I expect to be able to run a `->format()` on a FrozenTime object.

It's even more strange when running:

```
$b = new Cake\I18n\FrozenTime($moment);
debug($b);
debug($moment == $b);
```

`debug($b);` returns the same object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) showed above, and `debug($moment == $b);` returns `true`. And, guess what? `$b->format('G:i:s');` works at this point and it returns something like `1:00:50` (as I was expecting when calling `$session->time->format('G:i:s'));`

Is it a bug? Am I doing something wrong? Why two equal objects behavior in a different manner?

Should I rename the table and/or the field?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

Simple fact: the error was triggered just because ONE time column was returning NULL

It looks easy when you see it :)